# Why use download queues?

Tags: http, download, delay

I have seen a lot of websites using download queues. Some of them make users wait for a few minutes, so they can display ads and promote a payment version of their service, but sites like Sourceforge uses a 5 second queue and even offers a direct link for the impatient.

What can Sourceforge gain from introducing this 5 second delay?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? I think it's relevant to know if there any technical advantages, such as mirroring, hotlinking prevention, etc...  to putting people in a queue.

Answer (score 4):

there is ads on sourceforge download pages

Comment: I didn't notice because of Adblock, but I've just checked. Good point.

Comment: @TLama seems like an answer to me

Answer (score 1):

I think, in general it is 30% Bandwidth reduction and 70% Advertising Space

By making the user wait for only 5 seconds, the bandwidth is not affected this much.
However this fact applies better to hoster which have >30s delay.

From the advertisement point-of-view: Every second counts.
Sometimes it is enough to show a certain logo in order to make the consumer remind that one company. 
Even two or three sentences can still be read completely within 5 seconds!

Imagine you'd just see a big yellow `M`, I bet you'd associate it with a well known fast-food company! ;)

Comment: So there is definitely an advertising perspective to this, but is there any technical advantage?

Comment: As I said: For larger times, bandwidth reduction is definitely a reason. Just delay your downloads for a minute and you can serve files to twice as much people as before! (An earn money with it ;)

Comment: And annoy my users in the process. :)

I'm wondering if it contributes to prevent hotlinking. I've never worked on a site with significant downloadable content, so I've never thought of how to avoid hotlinking by other means than rejecting requests with a third party referer.

Comment: Hotlinking is like being parasite. If a website earns money by advertisements, they will suppress any activities which circument the display of their ad. So any ads financed website will prevent big amounts of hotlinking.